# How to implement ToggleGroup in fxml file, using Spring vs JavaFx

Tags: spring, javafx

Have `MainController`:

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML private RadioButton radioButton;
    @FXML private RadioButton radioButton2;

    @FXML public void addContact() {
        boolean b = radioButton.isSelected();
        boolean b2 = radioButton.isSelected();
    }
}
```

And `main.fxml`:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="350.0" prefWidth="755.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ru.habrahabr.ui.MainController">
      <TableView fx:id="table" editable="true" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="405.0" tableMenuButtonVisible="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
          <columnResizePolicy>
              <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
          </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>

      <HBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="207.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0">
            <RadioButton fx:id="radioButton" text="Male">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets right="3.0"/>
               </HBox.margin>
            </RadioButton>

            <RadioButton fx:id="radioButton2" text="Female">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets right="30.0"/>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0"/>
               </HBox.margin>
            </RadioButton>

            <Button minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addContact" text="Add" />
      </HBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

All is fine, but I need to combine the both Radio Buttons in the one group and I can not find a solution to how to implement something like `ToggleGroup` in `main.fxml`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not only `Node`s but also `ToggleGroup`s can be created in the fxml. Using [`<fx:reference>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#reference_elements) you can use an existing object:

```xml
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup?>

...
<RadioButton fx:id="radioButton" text="Male">
   <HBox.margin>
      <Insets right="3.0"/>
   </HBox.margin>
   <toggleGroup>
       <ToggleGroup fx:id="group"/>
   </toggleGroup>
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton fx:id="radioButton2" text="Female">
   <HBox.margin>
      <Insets right="30.0"/>
      <Insets bottom="10.0"/>
   </HBox.margin>
   <toggleGroup>
       <fx:reference source="group"/>
   </toggleGroup>
</RadioButton>
...
```

Alternatively use the `initialize` method of the controller for this purpose:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
    radioButton.setToggleGroup(group);
    radioButton2.setToggleGroup(group);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Following fabian's answer, you can define your toggle group in FXML then call it via the `toggleGroup` attribute. It works the same way but it is a little bit shorter.

```
<HBox ...>
    <fx:define>
        <ToggleGroup fx:id="group" />
    </fx:define>

    <RadioButton fx:id="radioButton" text="Male" toggleGroup="$group">
        <HBox.margin>
            <Insets right="3.0"/>
        </HBox.margin>
    </RadioButton>

    <RadioButton fx:id="radioButton2" text="Female" toggleGroup="$group">
        <HBox.margin>
            <Insets right="30.0" bottom="10.0"/>
        </HBox.margin>
    </RadioButton>

    <Button ... />
</HBox>
```

Comment: I liked this syntax until recently. I updated SceneBuilder from 11 to 16 and it stopped loading files with fx:define ToggleGroup but it works with fabian's method.

Comment: What about radio button's action? How to implement a method trigger in FXML?